# How to get the value after a string using perl reg expression

Tags: string, perl

I have the following string :

```
{\"id\":01,\"start_time\":\"1477954800000\",\"stop_time\":\"1485817200000\",\"url\":http:://www.example.com\}
```

and I'd like to get for example the value of start_time (1477954800000).
I tried several things  in https://regex101.com/ but I could not find a way to deal with the special characters (\":\") between the string and the value .

If the for example the string was like **start_time = 1477954800000**
I know that by using

```
start_time\":\"(\w+)/)
```

I'll get the value. 
Any idea on how to get the value when \":\" are involved?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew I'm coding in Perl

Comment: That looks like json. Why not decode it as json?

Comment: I know but I'd like to  familiarize with perl regex

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job. JSON is contextual and regex isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample data looks like a stringified JSON object, if that is the case you should use a JSON parser not a regular expression:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use JSON;

my $json_string = <DATA>;
chomp($json_string);

my $json_object = decode_json $json_string;

# get the value of the start_time key
say $json_object->{start_time};
# 1477954800000

__DATA__
{"id":1,"start_time":"1477954800000","stop_time":"1485817200000","url":"http://www.example.com"}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a literal JSON string(a string containing JSON data) within JSON-encoded data. That would explain the backslashes in front of all the double quotes. But then your solution still would be valid, just after `s/\\"/"/g` ;-)

Comment: I changed it slightly because of the way `__DATA__` works (everything under data is already literal data). If the above code was a function and you passed `"{\"id\":1,\"start_time\":\"1477954800000\",\"stop_time\":\"1485817200000\",\"url\":\"http://www.example.com\"}"` to it, it would still generate the correct result.

Comment: @SREagle Is it possible to give the exact command because I can't understand exactly what you mean. Sorry but I'm quite new in this stuff.

Comment: @dk13 Hunter McMillen kind of gave another (and probably better) solution: Just us perl's doublequote substition instead of my `s///` for the input string. ( `decode_json "$json_string"` instead of `decode_json $json_string` for your example string.) 'I'm not quite sure if perls and JSONs escape sequences are the same, but it's a start.